# How to trigger a parent's method only after event emitter sent from child and parent's ngIf condition is true?

Tags: angular, typescript

When the element in the child template is clicked, the method `activateService(name)` is executed and the event emitter `serviceSelected` (with alias 'service') is triggered, passing the name of the element clicked via selector to the parent's method `scrollDown(name)`. `scrollDown(name)` sets the parent's attribute `serviceActive` to `true` and should scroll down to the element with the `id='service-view'` in the parent's template. Now the problem is that I have to click the child's element twice until the parent's scroll down effect is triggered. It seems that by the time the child's value is passed to parent, the element in the parent's template is not visible yet. But I don't know how to condition the scroll down method to be triggered only after the `activeService` value has been set to true, that is, after the parent's element is visible. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

**Child:**

.ts:

```
@Output('service') serviceSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

activateService(service: string) {
   this.serviceSelected.next(service);
}
```

.html:

```
<div class="service" (click)="activateService('service1')">...</div>
```

**Parent:**

.ts:

```
serviceActive!: boolean;

scrollDown(evt: string) {
   this.onServiceActivated();
   document.getElementById("service-view")?.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start",
      inline: "nearest"
   });
}

onServiceActivated() {
   this.serviceActive = true;
}
```

.html:

```
<app-services (service)="scrollDown($event)"></app-services>

<!--Display only if serviceActive is true-->
<div id="service-view" *ngIf="serviceActive">
   <app-services-detail></app-services-detail>
</div>
```

Comment: could you make a short stackblitz with an example of your problem.

Comment: also I would suggest you make use of `@ViewChild` instead of `getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

parent `html`:

```
<div id="service-view" *ngIf="serviceActive">
   <app-services-detail #serviceView></app-services-detail>
</div>
```

parent `ts`:

```
@ViewhChildren("serviceView") serviceViews:QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLelement>>;

   ...

scrollDown(evt: string) {

  this.onServiceActivated();

}
   ...

ngAfterViewInit () {

   this.serviceViews.changes.pipe(
     filter( list => !!list.first ),
     tap( list => {

       list.first.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "start",
        inline: "nearest"
       });

     } )
   ).subscribe();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the scrolling element code in setTimeout like:

```
    scrollDown(evt: string) {
     this.onServiceActivated();
     setTimeoUT(()=>{
      document.getElementById("service-view")?.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start",
      inline: "nearest"
      });
     })
   }
```

It will add a little delay so that elements are visible in the DOM and the scrolling script will work.